# Headless firefox google maps not rendered in screenshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

When i try to take a screenshot in selenium (headless firefox driver) I get the following:
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2YvJ.png)

Is there any way to make the firefox driver render the maps like chrome?
also without running firefox in headless mode it renders it correctly

But on the chromedriver it does this correctly:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUARv.png)

It uses the same codebase between chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it simply doesn't support headless webgl yet see:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375585